Spring Boot management.metrics.distribution.percentiles examples
There's a config property for Spring Boot management.metrics.distribution.percentiles
the type of a value of the property is Map<String, double[]>
e.g. it may be set as following:
management.metrics.distribution.percentiles:
   all: 0.5, 0.95

the questions are:

what are some other common keys (like key=all) for the entries of this map? like can one restrict percentiles to http server requests only?
and where to look for them? (maybe some source code references?)
how can one define custom keys


The list of metric names can be found at /actuator/metrics endpoint.
And the custom metric names could be set in annotation like @Timed("exact.metric.name")


The answer to your first question is: yes, you can restrict percentiles to http server requests only.
You can refer to the Micrometer documentation and the Spring Boot Actuator documentation to find more built-in default metrics.
By specifying the exact metric name you can control the percentiles for that specific metrics.

Example:
management.metrics.distribution.percentiles:
  http.server.requests: 0.5, 0.95, 0.99
  foo.bar.custom.metric: 0.5, 0.9

